# How to use StrongNameKeyPair with a password protected keyfile (pfx)?

Tags: .net, code-signing, strongname, pkcs#12, assembly-signing

I am trying to programatically sign an assembly using a password protected keyfile (pfx). However when I try to use the StrongNameKeyPair I get the following exception.

Unable to obtain public key for StrongNameKeyPair.
   at System.Reflection.StrongNameKeyPair.ComputePublicKey()
   at System.Reflection.StrongNameKeyPair.get_PublicKey()

Comment: It would help us (and you) if you showed us the code you used to get that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not look like Microsoft updated [StrongNameKeyPair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.strongnamekeypair.aspx) to support anything other than the **snk** file format - as there's, sadly, no constructor accepting an RSA instance.

In fact my understanding is that the PKCS#12 [support](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=725#c8) for strongnaming assemblies is an indirect one, i.e. provided by the tools (msbuild or VS.NET) and not directly by the framework.

However you can still programatically sign an assembly using any RSA instance by re-using the (MIT.X11 licensed) code from Mono.Security [StrongName](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security/StrongName.cs) class, available in github. It's a bit more work - but it will work on any framework version and any (future) format that gets promoted :-)

Comment: StrongNameKeyPair has a constructor with a byte[] input. I Believe it's enough to build it from a PFX (see my answer).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a piece of C# code that creates a [StrongNameKeyPair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.strongnamekeypair%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) object from a password-protected .PFX file:

```
    public static StrongNameKeyPair GetStrongNameKeyPairFromPfx(string pfxFile, string password)
    {
        X509Certificate2Collection certs = new X509Certificate2Collection();
        certs.Import(pfxFile, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        if (certs.Count == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException(null, "pfxFile");

        RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = certs[0].PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
        if (provider == null) // not a good pfx file
            throw new ArgumentException(null, "pfxFile");

        return new StrongNameKeyPair(provider.ExportCspBlob(false));
    }
```

NOTE: I assume the PFX here has been created by the .NET Framework tools (for example the Visual Studio Strong Name UI form) to support an assembly strong name creation. It may not be ok with any PFX.

Comment: Although the X509Certificate2Collection is innecessary (just use X509Certificate2) this is the best solution i've found.

Comment: @Rafael - Absolutely. I saw that after the answer :-)